# Correct sentence tense and structure

Tags: sentence-construction

How can I say correctly that one day I will be a famous pianist and I will earn money by playing the piano?

“I will be playing the piano one day and I will be getting money from it.”

what is the correct future tense?
can I say “from it”?
and actually can I say that this way? - would it be better to say “I will get paid for it.” ....I would like to express that I won’t be just paid as for job but I would be paid fortune because I will be good as a Ray Charles.

Answer (score 1):

Some day I'll play piano for a living and make a fortune at it.

Comment: Could it be
Some day I'll play piano for a living and make money at it.?

Comment: Yes, asolutely.

Comment: Any other preposition would be possible in “make money AT it”? Kind regards

Comment: You **could** say "make money **from** it," but that sounds a little bit off (i.e., not quite right).

Comment: And how about: ”Some/one day, I will be/become a pianist and I will get paid for it.”     Second sentence is ok? Some or one? be or become? Thank you so much

Comment: Yeah, they're OK, though *be* is a bit better than *become*. And the second *will* would usually be dropped: "be a pianist and get paid for it."